# show datas in the datatable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have data stored in table I need to show that data into datatable,
it throws an error I have no idea what it is, please help I am a newbie to laravel, had used this code in my other project but it doesn't work on this
it throws error undefined variable branch in the index file specifically in data table part

Index

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card m-b-30">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Branch Details</h4>
                    <p class="text-muted m-b-30 font-14">
                    </p>

                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Dealership</th>
                            <th>Branch Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <?php $i = 1; ?>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($branch as $branch)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                                <?php
                                $del=Dealership::where('dlr_id',$branch->dlr_id)->first();
                                ?>
                                <td>{{$del->dlr_id}}</td>
                                <?php
                                $com=Company::where('comp_id',$branch->comp_id)->first();
                                ?>
                                <td>{{$com->comp_id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$branch->name}}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{route('branch.edit',$branch->id)}}"><img src="assets/images/edit.png" class="imgsize"></a> </td>
                                <td><a href="{{route('branch.delete',$branch->id)}}"><img src="assets/images/delete.png" class="imgsize"></a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $i++;?>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </div>
```

Controller file

class BranchController extends Controller
{

```
public function index()
{
    $companies=Company::where('status','0')
        ->get();
   $dealership=Dealership::where('status','0')->get();
$branch=Branch::where('status','0')->get();
    return view('branch.index',['companies'=>$companies],['dealership'=>$dealership],['branch'=>$branch]);
}


public function store(Request $request)
{
    $branch_id = new Branch;
    $branch_id=Branch::orderBy('br_id','desc')->take(1)->get();
    if(count($branch_id)>0)
    {
        $id= $branch_id[0]->br_id;
        $id=$id+1;
    }
    else
    {
        $id=1;
    }
    $branch = new Branch;
    $branch->br_id=$id;
    $branch->name= $request->input('branch');
    $branch->dlr_id= $request->input('dealer');
    $branch->comp_id= $request->input('compnay');
    $branch->created_id= '0';
    $branch->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully saved');
```

}}
}

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Branch extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable=[
        'br_id',
        'name',
        'dlr_id',
        'created_id',
        'status',
        'comp_id'
    ];
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
    public function dealership()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dealership');
    }
    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `<?php $i = 1; ?>` and `<?php $i++; ?>` and replace your output `{{ $i }}` with `{{ $loop->iteration }}`, which does the same thing and is built into the `foreach` directive (see [The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable)).

Comment: Please create a new question with this issue if the original one is answered. It will be much easier to answer to that and for others to follow along if they have the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing three distinct arrays to your `view` method, rather than a single array with all options. Also, in your view you're using the same name for the collection of branches as for the individual branch (`branch`), which leads to a naming conflict.

In your Controller's `index` method, use this instead:

```
$branches = Branch::where('status','0')->get();
return view('branch.index',['companies'=>$companies, 'dealership'=>$dealership, 'branches'=>$branches]);
```

In your `foreach` blade directive, use the new `$branches` variable:

```
@foreach ($branches as $branch)
    <!-- ... -->
@endforeach
```

---

If you add loads of variables to your views you might find it easier and more readable to use the [`compact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) method like so:

```
return view('branch.index', compact('companies', 'dealership', 'branches'));
```

This will create the same array as above as long as the variables `$companies`, `$dealership` and `$branches` are defined.

Comment: Overlooked the main issue with your code, fixed my answer

Comment: Now it throws anaother error                                                                            Class 'Dealership' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Accessories\resources\views\branch\index.blade.php)

Comment: That is because you execute raw PHP code within your Blade template and access the `Dealership` class from the global namespace, although it is likely in some namespace like `App` (`App\Dealership`). In your case it would make sense to use [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) for the `Company` and `Dealership` models that are tied to your `Branch` model so you don't have to use PHP in your templates.